# Duplicate email alert when change an order status in workflow rule

Tags: workflow, email-alert

Have an issue. I have a workflow which has to send an email notification when the status of an order is changed to 'In queue'. But it sends it twice. No one process builder or trigger use this email alert. Nothing from the internet works.
Workflow:
[image]

Email alert:

[image]

Here are some logs. May be it can help somebody to help me :)

[image]

Comment: Can you check if you have any other workflow rules on that object which is updating the field and has `Re-evaluate Workflow Rules After Field Change` enabled ?

Comment: @VijayGanji no only one workflow on the order

Comment: Can you try changing From Email Address to 'Default Workflow User's email address' in Email alert?